# How to display selected values in Angular Materials table?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am attempting to display values as follows:

| Asteroid Number | Selected Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1566 | some value |
| 1842 | some value |
| etc. | some value |

Here are the HTML and TypeScript:

**TypeScript**

```
import { Asteroid } from '../models/asteroid.model';
import { DataSource } from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AsteroidService } from '../_services/asteroid.service';
import { AsteroidCharacteristics } from '../enums/characteristic.enum';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-asteroid-details',
  templateUrl: './asteroid-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asteroid-details.component.scss']
})

export class AsteroidDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource = new AsteroidDataSource(this.asteroidService);
  optionsForm: FormControl = new FormControl();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["name", "characteristics"];
  charOptions: string[] = [
    AsteroidCharacteristics.semimajor_axis,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.eccentricity,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.perihelion_distance,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.perihelion_date,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.aphelion_distance,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.aphelion_date,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.delta_v,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.diameter,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.price,
    AsteroidCharacteristics.mass
  ];


  constructor(private readonly asteroidService: AsteroidService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}

export class AsteroidDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  data = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Asteroid>>(undefined);
  variable = getSelection();
  constructor(private readonly asteroidService: AsteroidService) {
    super();
    asteroidService.asteroidData.subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }

  connect(): Observable<Array<Asteroid>> {
    console.log("data:" + this.data);
    return this.data;
  }
  disconnect() {}

  getSelection(value){
    if (value == "Semimajor Axis"){
      var select = "semimajor";
    }
    else if (value == "Eccentricity"){
    var select = "eccentricity";
    }
    else if (value == "Perihelion Distance"){
      var select = "perihelion_distance";
    }
    else if (value == "Perihelion Date"){
      var select = "perihelion_date";
    }
    else if (value == "Aphelion Distance"){
      var select = "aphelion_distance";
    }
    else if (value == "Aphelion Date"){
      var select = "aphelion_date";
    }
    else if (value == "Velocity"){
      var select = "delta_v";
    }
    else if (value == "Diameter"){
      var select = "diameter";
    }
    else if (value == "Price"){
      var select = "price";
    }
    else if (value == "Mass"){
      var select = "mass";
    }
    return select;
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <p>asteroid-details table</p>
    <!-- <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="asteroidDetailsList" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

    </table> -->
    <table mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Asteroid Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let asteroid"> {{ asteroid.number }} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="characteristics">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-select placeholder="Characteristic"[formControl]="optionsForm">
                        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let char of charOptions" [value]="char">{{ char }}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let asteroid"> {{ asteroid.variable }} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="optionsForm.value === 'Mass'">
            <tr mat-row *ngFor="let asteroid of asteroidData">asteroid.mass</tr>
        </ng-container> -->
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

More specifically, how can I assign a value from the selection to the table? If I manually enter a value (asteroid.eccentricity or asteroid.semimajor_axis) it correctly displays the values.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you having a particular issue passing the events in [like they show in the docs example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection) or something different?

Comment: We have gone over the documentation and this example in particular. I honestly wish that we could better tell you where our issue lies. Unfortunately, we've tried a lot for about 3 days now.